# Building XPCOM XULRunner 2.0 or newer versions

Tags: c++, mozilla, xpcom, xulrunner, gecko

Followup to the following Questions:

[What lib in the gecko 1.9.3 SDK do I link against to use moz_xmalloc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459033/what-lib-in-the-gecko-1-9-3-sdk-do-i-link-against-to-use-moz-xmalloc)

[nsIGenericFactory.h is missing in the above version of xulrunner-2.0.en-US.win32.sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532850/nsigenericfactory-h-is-missing-in-the-above-version-of-xulrunner-2-0-en-us-win32)

I am able to build XPCOM with XULRunner 1.9.2 successfully.

When I try to migrate to the next versions of XULRunner (> 1.9), I am facing lot of difficulties. I am getting Link errors like the following

```
xpcomglue_s.lib(GenericFactory.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
xpcomglue_s.lib(nsCRTGlue.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
xpcomglue_s.lib(nsTArray.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
xpcomglue_s.lib(nsComponentManagerUtils.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
xpcomglue_s.lib(GenericModule.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
xpcomglue_s.lib(nsISupportsImpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__moz_xmalloc
```

I am not getting clear steps for migration to support for the current FireFox.

I tried the suggestions mentioned in the links. I could not resolve it. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: more warnings: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned int __cdecl NS_NewGenericModule2(struct nsModuleInfo const *,class nsIModule * *)" referenced in function _NSGetModule comp-module.obj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hopeing someone would provide a full list of what should be changed to get it working on later gecko, but since no one did it, I'll try to do it myself, using [this](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/sample/) sample I just found.

### xpidl.exe

I don't know if this has changed or not, so this might not be necessary. There's no xpidl.exe in Gecko 11. The solution for this from **Philip Chee**

> It has been replaced by a Python script. You can continue using the
>   XPIDL from the Gecko 7.0 SDK, or compile it from source, or use the
>   Python script.

Gecko 7.0 can be downloaded from ftp [HERE](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/7.0.1/sdk/). It truly has the xpidl.exe. The usage is the same as in the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_build_a_binary_XPCOM_component_using_Visual_Studio#Create_an_XPCOM_Component)

### Component module implementation

This one seems like it changed a lot. [Reference in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0#Binary_components) and [another reference](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/zOxEyIVzkcnAm06VMF9A) (which goes back to the sample provided on top, but explains stuff).

> Note that nsIGenericFactory.h has been removed. References to
>   nsIGenericFactory.h should be replaced with mozilla/ModuleUtils.h

In the sample project `#include "nsIClassInfoImpl.h"` is also added.

Now the biggest step is to change the `NS_IMPL_NSGETMODULE` (which is also removed), and the declaration of the `components`, which is used by that to the whole bunch of stuff found in the [sample module](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/sample/nsSampleModule.cpp). You could use the declaration of the `components` for reference, I did, helps a bit.

The only thing you don't need from that sample is the declaration and usage of `kSampleCategories`. Just replace it with `NULL`. At least that's what **Benjamin Smedberg** [said](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/zOxEyIVzkcnAm06VMF9A#71agT6wzNLD8v03).

The constant `kNS_SAMPLE_CID` should be replaced with `kYOUR_CID_CONSTANT`. Just prepend k to you CID constant name.

This last line:

```
NS_IMPL_MOZILLA192_NSGETMODULE(&kSampleModule)
```

is only needed for compatibility with Gecko 1.9. Since firefox 3.5 uses that, I'll think I'll leave it.

### Component implementation (CompImpl.cpp)

Reference from [sample](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/sample/nsSample.cpp).

- Add the `NS_IMPL_CLASSINFO...` line (in the sample it's line 80)
- Replace `NS_IMPL_ISUPPORTS1` with `NS_IMPL_ISUPPORTS1_CI`

In this sample there are a bunch of good examples on how to use input / output values. If you want to use char* you also need to use nsMemory. I think for nsStrings this is not necessary.

### [XPCOM Glue without mozalloc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Glue/XPCOM_Glue_without_mozalloc)

Here we are again, bunch of linking errors to `__imp__moz_xmalloc`. This little, really hard to find, article helped get rid of them:

> Starting with XULRunner 2.0, the frozen linkage dependent glue
>   (xpcomglue_s.lib on Windows, libxpcomglue_s.a on Linux and Mac) is
>   dependent on the new infallible memory allocation routines (mozalloc).
>   Since these routines didn't exist prior to XULRunner 2.0, XPCOM
>   components that link against the frozen linkage dependent glue will
>   not be compatible with XULRunner applications prior to 2.0.
>
> The solution is to link against xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc instead
>   (xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib on Windows, libxpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.a on
>   Linux and Mac).  This library is new in XULRunner 2.0, and it's
>   identical to xpcomglue_s, except that it's compiled without mozalloc. 
>   Simply change all references to "xpcomglue_s" in your compiler and
>   linker flags to "xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc".  Resulting XPCOM components
>   will no longer have a dependency on mozalloc, and will thus be
>   compatible with XULRunner applications prior to 2.0 as well.
>
> Comment: You might also need to build your component with the
>   MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC flag (-DMOZ_NO_MOZALLOC)

**And finally, there is no error**

Answer (score 1):

[This seems to be a common problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459033/what-lib-in-the-gecko-1-9-3-sdk-do-i-link-against-to-use-moz-xmalloc) I see you've already found this thread and tried the standard advice, but for the benefit of others:

> define `'XPCOM_GLUE'` in C++ Preprocessor Definition property. It will
>   fix the linking error.

Since you already have this in place, the next fix you should try is actually further down the page:

> Try defining `MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC` when compiling your extension, you will
>   then get a DLL that uses your CRT's allocators. (Don't forget to use
>   [the NS_* allocators for XPCOM-compatible memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_API_Reference).)

You can do this by adding `#define MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC` to the contents of your extension, to `configure` when you build XULRunner, or in the contents of individual files such as your `mozilla-config.h`.

Although it's exceedingly likely you've tried this already, it *should* resolve your linker issue, at least.

**Edit:** For the benefit of the bounty provider, [here's advice to resolve the `__cdecl NS_NewGenericModule2` issue.](http://alexandrucristei.blogspot.com/2009/07/unresolved-external-nsnewgenericmodule2.html)

Comment: actually I did not do the "Try defining MOZ_NO_MOZALLOC ..." part, because I didn't really understand it, mainly the part in the brackets, I would be really grateful if you'd write about that in more detail

Comment: @SinistraD Added an additional sentence detailing how to do this.

Comment: I meant the "Don't forget to use the NS_* allocators" part (the one in the brackets). And btw, none of these defines made the warnings disappear

Comment: @SinistraD I believe [this reference is what's being referred to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_API_Reference). The poster is pointing out to make sure that you use the NS_* memory calls in the API reference to ensure XPCOM manages the underlying `malloc` and `free`. This makes sense, because you just turned off the functions in [mozalloc.h](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla/html/mozalloc_8h.html).